# Parse out date from filename and sort by date

Tags: powershell

I have a series of files named as such in a folder:
 - myFile201801010703.file

I'm trying to parse out the yyyymmdd portion of each filename in the folder and sort them based on the date into an array.

So if I had the following files:

- myFile201801200000.file (01/20/2018)
- myFile201800100000.file (01/01/2018)
- myFile201801100000.file (01/10/2018)

It would sort them into an array as such:

- myFile201800100000.file (01/01/2018)
- myFile201801100000.file (01/10/2018)
- myFile201801200000.file (01/20/2018)

I have a process that works for file with timestamps included in the name, though have been unable to tweak it for work with only a date:

```cs
    # RegEx pattern to parse the timestamps
    $Pattern = '(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})*\' + ".fileExtension"
    $FilesList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $Temp = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder | ForEach {
        if ($_.Name -match $Pattern) {
            Write-Verbose "Add $($_.Name)" -Verbose
            $Date = $Matches[2],$Matches[3],$Matches[1] -join '/'
            $Time = $Matches[4..6] -join ':'
            [void]$Temp.Add(
                (New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Date = [datetime]"$($Date) $($Time)" #If I comment out $($Time)it doesn't work.
                    File = $_
                }
            ))
        }
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "`n*** $Error ***`n"
}

# Sort the files by the parsed timestamp and add to $FilesList
$FilesList.AddRange(@($Temp | Sort Date | Select -Expand File))

# Clear out the temp collection
$Temp.Clear()
```

The two lines in particular that I think might be culprit are:

`$Time = $Matches[4..6] -join ':'` Since I'm not parsing any time

`Date = [datetime]"$($Date) $($Time)"` Again, no time is parsed. Can't change the type to date either it seems?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Sorry Jeff- Included my current code.:)

Comment: Quick fix: `$Time='00:00:00'`

Comment: Or format your date as YYYY-MM-DD: `$Date = $Matches[1],$Matches[2],$Matches[3] -join '-'`

Comment: The date format in the file name is already sortable - why go through all these hoops?

Comment: @JohnLBevan Adding your two suggestions gives me the following error:
Cannot convert value "2018-01-00 00:00:00" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen I don't know any other way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With this format:

```
myFileYYYYMMddHHmm.file
```

the individual parts of the date and time is already arranged from largest (the year) to smallest (the minute) - this makes the string sortable!

Only thing we need to do is grab the last 12 digits of the file name before the extension:

```
$SortedArray = Get-ChildItem *.file |Sort-Object {$_.BaseName -replace '^.*(\d{12})$','$1'}
```

---

The regex pattern used:

```
^.*(\d{12})$
```

Can be broken down as follows:

```
^              # start of string
  .*           # any character, 0 or more times
    (          # capture group
     \d{12}    # any digit, 12 times
           )   # end of capture group
            $  # end of string
```

The regex engine will expand `$1` in the substitution string to "capture group #1", ie. the 12 digits we picked up at the end.

Comment: That works perfectly. I need t look into that last little bit to figure out what it's doing. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AaronJohnsen You're most welcome! I added an explanation for the regex pattern